# python string formatting error in a definite loop

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
def main():
    #Get amount of principal, apr, and # of years from user
    princ = eval(input("Please enter the amount of principal in dollars "))
    apr = eval(input("Please enter the annual interest rate percentage "))
    years = eval(input("Please enter the number of years to maturity "))

    #Convert apr to a decimal
    decapr = apr / 100

    #Use definite loop to calculate future value
    for i in range(years):
        princ = princ * (1 + decapr)
        print('{0:5d} {0:5d}'.format(years, princ))
```

I'm trying to print the years and the principal value in a table, but when I print all that comes out is two columns of 10.

Comment: You have three places where user input is requested. What input are you providing when your problem occurs?

Answer (score 2):

So you have several problems.  The first problem is a display issue.

Your output statement `print('{0:5d} {0:5d}'.format(years, princ))` has several issues.

1. printing years instead of i, so it's always the same value instead of incrementing
2. the `0` in the format statement`{0:5d}` means the 0'th element out of the following values, so you're actually printing years twice, the second one should be `1` instead of `0`
3. you're using `d` to print what should be a floating point value, d is for printing integers, you should be using something along the lines of `{1:.2f}` which means "print this number with 2 decimal places

Once you've corrected those you'll still see incorrect answers because of a more subtle problem.  You're performing division with integer values rather than floating point numbers, this means that any decimal remainders are truncated, so `apr / 100` will evaluate to 0 for any reasonable apr.

You can fix this problem by correcting your input.  (As a side note, running eval on user input is usually an incredibly dangerous idea, since it will execute any code that is entered.)  Instead of eval, use `float` and `int` to specify what types of values the input should be converted to.

The following is corrected code which implements the above fixes.

```
#Get amount of principal, apr, and # of years from user
princ = float(input("Please enter the amount of principal in dollars "))
apr = float(input("Please enter the annual interest rate percentage "))
years = int(input("Please enter the number of years to maturity "))

#Convert apr to a decimal
decapr = apr / 100

#Use definite loop to calculate future value
for i in range(years):
    princ = princ * (1 + decapr)
    print('{0} {1:.2f}'.format(i, princ))
```